# jQuery code unable to run

Tags: jquery

i would like to ask what is wrong with my jquery code which cause it not to run. I am trying to select columns from this table using selectable and getting the information out from each td

```
$(function() {
    $( "table" ).selectable({
        filter: ".tdItem"
        stop: function() {
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(
                function() {

                }
            );
        }
    });
});

});
```

Comment: Press F12 - any errors or messages in your console output?

Comment: You have an extra `});` at the end too

Comment: It's nice that people trust SO in asking questions, but I worry that our community is turning into live human debuggers. OP should be able (or instructed) to detect such errors...

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a comma after:

```
filter: ".tdItem",
```

Also the last `});` (unless it's connected to something else, would give you a: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }** error.

Comment: Thanks Gaby, forgot that would give you an error as well (just assumed it was maybe a copy/paste mistake)

Answer (score 3):

No comma between filter and stop. Also an extra }); Not sure if these are just copy paste errors though.

```
$(function() {
    $("table").selectable({
        filter: ".tdItem",
        stop: function() {
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(
                function() {

                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```